A 3D integral (Hylleraas wave function)
In quantum mechanical context I would like to evaluate this function (Hylleraas type wave function for Helium atom ground state):
$$ I(\boldsymbol{r}) = \int_{R^3} d^3 r' e^{- a_1 r'} \Vert \boldsymbol{r} - \boldsymbol{r'} \Vert $$
Where $\boldsymbol{r} = (x,y,z)$ the 3D position vector. I know that it gives this:
$$ I(\boldsymbol{r}) = \int_0^{+ \infty} r'^2 d r' \int_0^{2 \pi} d \phi' \\ \int_0^{\pi} \sin \theta' d \theta' e^{- a_1 r'} \sqrt{r^2 + r'^2 - 2 r r' \left( \sin \theta' \sin \theta \cos(\phi-\phi') + \cos \theta ' \cos \theta \right)} $$
That seems difficult to integrate directly, there is maybe a useful technique to compute this expression ?
Do this expression depends only on radial $r$ coordinate (seems obvious but maybe difficult to prove it)?
HINT
I was thinking of the inverse of Laplace expansion but I do not think it is good idea.

$\textbf{Hint:}$ There are a few simplifications you can take. The most important one is that you have the freedom to align the $\mathbf{r}$ vector along the $z'$ axis, making the cross term in the square root simply $2rr'\cos\theta'$. Now the integrand is a simple antiderivative in both of the angular variables. Can you finish the computation from here?

Thanks mate ! Yes I was not sure I can orient the $\boldsymbol{r}$ vector along a particular axis to get rid of the $\Phi'$ integral. So this integral depends only on the radial component too. The integral on $\theta'$ is easy, I checked on "integral calculator" ;)
